# How to Read decimal numbers from a user in C#?

Tags: c#

so I'm 3 weeks new to programming and I am trying to make a basic Console calculator using C#. I do not know how to read a decimal (eg. `5.5`) from a user. Normal *integers* (e.g. `5`) work though. I get the below *exception error*:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

This is the code:

```
Console.WriteLine(
  "Hi there, My name is Mohammed.\n" +
  "Today we are going to be doing several calculations.\n\n" +
  "These would include Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication and Division. ");

Console.WriteLine("To get started, please hit the space key.");
Console.ReadKey();

Console.WriteLine("We will start with a addition. Please enter the first number.");
double num01 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Now enter the second number");
double num02 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

double ans01 = (num01 + num02);
Console.WriteLine(num01 + "+" + num02 + " is equals to " + ans01 + 
    "\nGreat, now lets move on to subtraction. Please enter the first number.");
```

Comment: Try `Convert.ToDouble("5.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Yeah this is probably a culture issue.  This code looks fine to me.

Comment: How do you write a decimal number in the culture your computer is set for? is it `5.5` or `5,5` or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert decimal numbers from string to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418853/convert-decimal-numbers-from-string-to-double)

Comment: Thank you so much. My computer culture is set to `,` and I was using `.` It is now working. Thanks to all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input string was not in a correct format #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275380/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-2)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest *method extraction*, something like this:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

private static double ReadDouble(string title)
{
    while (true) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(title);

        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        double result;

        // We use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to ensure that
        // decimal separator is dot (.). i.e. we expect 5.5 input
        if (double.TryParse(userInput, 
                            NumberStyles.Any, 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            out result))
        {
            return result;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, incorrect format. Enter it again, please.");  
    }
}
```

Then we can use the routine

```
...
Console.ReadKey();

double num01 = ReadDouble("We will start with a addition. Please enter the first number.");

double num02 = ReadDouble("Now enter the second number");

double ans01 = (num01 + num02);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the current culture on your computer. You can go to `Control Panel` and click `Region and Language`. From there, click `Additional settings` button at the bottom. It should take you to the `Customize Format` page like below

[image: Customize Format Page]

This page tells you how to enter a decimal number on your console. The above steps are for Win 7 machine. You can then try the following C# code to verify the working from the immediate window on Visual Studio

```
double.Parse("5.5");
double.Parse("5,5");
```

The correct format will not throw an Exception in the immediate window (or temp code)

Also, the same `Decimal symbol` can be extracted via C# using the below code

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PercentDecimalSeparator
```