# (C#) I'm having trouble with the Convert function in regard to strings

Tags: c#

I'm very new to programming and I wanted to create a small console app that calculates Force when given 2 charges and the distance between them according to Coulomb's Law.
I seem to be having a problem with converting strings to decimals.
I'm not quite sure how to multiply multiple stings( Q1, Q2 and r)

This is an image of my code along with the console display and error message.
[image: console output]

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Dieter's Coulomb's Law Calculator!");
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue.");

String Q1;
String Q2;
String r;
Decimal k = (9 * 10 ^ 9); 

Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("All you need to do is insert the first charge, the second chage and the distance between them.");
Console.WriteLine("Remember to give your values in coulombs and meters.");
Console.WriteLine("Charge 1: ");
Q1 = (Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Charge 2: ");
Q2 = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Distance in m: ");
r = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(" Equation: k*|Q1*Q2|/r^2");
Console.WriteLine("Equation: " + "9*10^9*" + "|" + Q1 + "*" + Q2 + "|" + "/" + r + "^2" );

Decimal ans = ( k * Convert.ToDecimal(Q1) * Convert.ToDecimal(Q2) / Convert.ToDecimal(r) * Convert.ToDecimal(r));
Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + ans);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: what is the value in `Q1, Q2 and r`

Comment: @un-lucky see the console window

Comment: For Q1..  +5*10^-3 probably isn't valid input to Convert.ToDecimal. In that it can't be directly parsed as a decimal number

Comment: First calculate the result of your calculation and convert the result to a decimal

Comment: Please, do not post an image with your code. It is impossible for us to test your code unless we start typing it from scratch. It is pretty absurd. Code is made of text, just copy/paste your code in your answer and use the {} button to format it

Comment: un-lucky, r should be a normal decimal. but an example of what Q1 could be is +5*10^-3

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments by [Nattrass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1205182/nattrass) `+5*10^-3` is not a valid input for `Convert.ToDecimal()`.

I assume you want the user to enter the numbers in exponential notation.

So I suggest to change your console input from `+5*10^-3` to `5E-3` and use the following snippet to parse your decimal using [`NumberStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System.Globalization;

...

// with any you did not have to care about decimal points and thousand sign
// leading sign and so on..
decimal Q1 = Decimal.Parse("5E-3", NumberStyles.Any); // Q1 = 0.005

// or explicit:
decimal Q2 = Decimal.Parse("-1E-1", NumberStyles.AllowExponent 
                                    | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint 
                                    | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign);  // Q2 = -0,1
```

But we have to be careful with the decimal point (dot or comma) so you can just add `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to the parse method.

```
decimal Q2 = Decimal.Parse( "-1E-1", NumberStyles.AllowExponent 
                                     | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint 
                                     | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign,
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

Your code has also some other issues.

For example calculating your constant `Decimal k = (9 * 10 ^ 9);`
You are using the `^` operator to indicate the power of 9 by a base of ten but in C# it is used as [XOR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator). So you should use the [`Math.Pow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) to calculate your constant.

```
decimal k = (decimal)(9 * Math.Pow(10,9));
```

You should also avoid `Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());`, because the return value is already a type of `string`.
You can instead try to cast the input from your console to `decimal` and avoid the multiple casting in the later code, when calculating. This link may help you to extend your code: [How to Read decimal numbers from a user in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46118164/5893316()()